# Weird occasional exception connecting to SQL server - "something that is not a socket"

Tags: .net, sql-server, winsock, sqlclient

I have two Windows servers in production, one runs SQL Server server database, another is a web-server running an ASP.NET app in IIS. Heavy traffic between the two.

Occasionally I get this random error (several times an hour):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level
>   error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider:
>   TCP Provider, error: 0 - **An operation was attempted on something
>   that is not a socket.**) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): An operation was attempted on something that is not a
>   socket

Tried Googling, haven't found anything.

Tried resetting winsock and tcp/ip by running `netch winsock reset` and `netsh int ip reset` - didn't help.

Obviously it is some random connectivity issue...

P.S. this started happening after I stop-started a server in AWS, which means it now runs on different hardware with new private IP address... Not sure it's related. Probably not.

Comment: I'd suspect that something is mismanaging handles within your process. Immediate suspects would be if you've got unmanaged code or are P/Invoking heavily.

Comment: Never say never when clouds, especially AWS is involved. There *are* issues both with disk and network IO, especially for older OSs and SQL Server versions. Older OS versions, or older VM types have weaker paravirtualization support. They may run on weaker host hardware. We've encountered both disk and network issues with AWS. Moving the *web site* to  Windows 2016 and a newer VM size gave us 40+% perf improvements for the same price essentially.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks! yes, it DOES LOOK LIKE its related to AWS, I'm currently diving into this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/pvdrivers-troubleshooting.html#citrix-tcp-offloading apparently I need to upgrade my network drivers from "Citrix" to "AWS PV"... Thanks, I guess I'm on the right track.

Comment: @jitbit you can't imagine the PAIN of having to wait for MS bashers to bash before they admitted it's the cloud. Even when the Event Viewer was filled with IO errors. Anyway, check the newer VMs. The pricing difference may be pennies, but the boost from fresher OS, HW is significant

Comment: @jitbit apart from that, it's a cloud. Connectivity failures are *guaranteed*. Your code should be able to reconnect/retry. That's why ADO.NET and EF added reconnection and retry policies 1-2 years ago.

Comment: @jitbit we went from C3 to C4.